# How to find the issue in a git-patch?

Tags: git, devops, patch

A coworker of mine has to submit his commits using `git send-email` but for some reason some of his patches can not be `git am`'d. When looking at source-state in patch and repo they look identical.

Is there a way to get more detailed errors than "something wrong with this line"?

Comment: Please explain more. What happens if you do *not* do `git am`? (which is not a real command by the way, did you mean `git commit -am`?)

Comment: There could be differences like tabs and spaces, CR and CRLF.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: `git am` means "apply mailbox": you feed it several `git format-patch` email messages in the form of a Unix-style mailbox, and it tries to `git apply` and `git commit` each one.

Comment: Without access to the repository and the mbox file, it's hard to say. Whitespace, as @ElpieKay mentioned, might differ.

Comment: agh, so `git am` *is* a real command, wonder why it gave me an error when I tried it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Unfortunately since it is a work project I am not able to provide access to the sourcefiles. Thank you for the idea with the whitespaces though @ElpieKay I completely forgot about these.